How do I make a late initialised IUO property nonisolated?
I have a ObservableObject (AppObservableObject) that is observed on a couple of Views in my app. I annotated it with @MainActor so that I ensure all view updates are sent through the Main thread.
However, the observable object has a config variable that is pulled from a API and it is initialised further along in the app than when I initialise my AppObservableObject. Since the config is pulled once and doesn't change, it is not Published and may be marked nonisolated. But therein lies my problem. I cannot annotate it as such.
I could move the config out of the Observable Object as a last resort, but I wonder if I could make it work as is.
@MainActor
class AppObservableObject: ObservableObject {
    
    static var shared: AppObservableObject = AppObservableObject()
    
    @Published var appState: AppState = AppState()
    /*nonisolated*/ var config: AppConfig! // <----- 'nonisolated' can not be applied to stored properties
}

What is the right course of action here?

Why do you want config to be non-isolated? It is not safe to do so.

I'm interested in how you plan to "move the config out of the Observable Object" , in a thread-safe way.

The config is set only once per app instance and never mutated post that. It's just a static JSON that contains some string copies, that is pulled from a API, decoded and set to the config variable. By "moving" it, I was thinking I could create a singleton in the AppConfig definition itself.

nonisolated cannot be applied to a stored property because it is not safe to do so.
By making a property nonisolated, it can be read and written to by different threads at the same time.
If the property is a computed property, it could be safe depending on what you are doing in the getter and setter. The compiler will place restrictions on what you can do in the getter/setter, such as preventing you from modifying isolated properties.
If the property is a stored var, then Swift can immediately conclude that this is not safe. One thread can read the var while another is writing to it, and there you have a data race.
Note this is not a problem if the enclosing class is itself not isolated to an actor, because then the class is not Sendable, and it is unsafe for an instance to escape to another thread. Swift will warn/error you if you try to do that.
If you can guarantee that config will be written to exactly once, and that no one will read its value before the write finishes, you can mark it as nonisolated(unsafe). I would also introduce an additional backing property to avoid the use of implicitly-unwrapped optionals.
private nonisolated(unsafe) var _config: AppConfig?

nonisolated var config: AppConfig {
    get { _config! }
    set {
        assert(_config == nil)
        _config = newValue
    }
}

However, I would strongly recommend you to keep it isolated to the main actor.
